# .bat манипуляция датой

Tags: bat

Есть задача получить в переменной дату на месяц вперед от текущей в .bat в формате `хх/хх/хх`.

Подскажите, как сделать на примере.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, нормальный вопрос.

Comment: Нашел пример. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetiment.php#DateAdd Дата преобразуется в Юлианский формат -- количество дней. К полученному количеству можно добавить ещё 30 дней и преобразовать дату назад в формат YYYY MM DD.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%a in ( "%date%" ) do (
    set d=%%a
    set m=%%b
    set y=%%c
)
if %m%==09 set m=10
set nextmd=%d%/%m%/%y%
echo %nextmd%
```

Для остальных месяцев сам.

Answer (score 1):

На JS можно вычислить дату так:

```
var myDate = new Date();
var dayOfMonth = myDate.getDate();
myDate.setDate(dayOfMonth + 30);
var out = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
var formatDate = myDate.getFullYear() 
    + "/" 
    + (myDate.getMonth()+1) 
    + "/" 
    + myDate.getDate();
out.Write(formatDate);
```

JS из bat можно вызвать так:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (
    `@"%systemroot%\system32\mshta.exe" "javascript:try {var myDate = new Date();var dayOfMonth = myDate.getDate();myDate.setDate(dayOfMonth + 30);var out = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1); var formatDate = myDate.getFullYear() + "/" + (myDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + myDate.getDate(); out.Write(formatDate)}; catch (e){}; close();" ^
    1^|more`
) do set sDateTime=%%i


echo %sDateTime%

endlocal
```

Результат:
    2015/10/23

Сегодня 23 сентября 2015 года.

Код взял тут:

http://forum.script-coding.com/viewtopic.php?id=5066

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee532932%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: У меня сегодня 22 сентября. Откуда это ты пишешь?

Comment: @Tpaxtibidox, точно. Вчера на планете Земля в России было 22 сентября. Значит что-то не учёл, и в коде есть подводный камень.